# knitr cache and ggplot2::last_plot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

Is there a way of make it so that knitr caches stuff so that `last_plot()` works properly? For example this document:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, cache = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
```


```{r cars}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
   geom_point()
```

The first value is  `r last_plot()$data$mpg[1]`
````

The first time is generated, it will have one figure and the text "The first value is 21". But the second time, the last inline code will fail.

Comment: Can you assign it to a object and extract i.e. `p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
   geom_point();
p1` and `r p1$data$mpg[1]` worked fine

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for something that doesn't force me to change the code of a chunk if I want to refer to the plot.